# Property 'length' does not exist on type 'void' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this child component `slide1.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slide1',
  templateUrl: './slide1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slide1.component.css'],
})
export class Slide1Component implements OnInit {
  @Input() select_option: string;
  @Output('answer') answer: EventEmitter<{
    Res: any;
    Ans: any;
  }> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  callchild() {
    var res = this.answer.emit({ Res: '', Ans: '' });
    console.log(res.length);
    console.log('child ');
  }
}
```

> res.length

getting `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'void'.` but this method which is in parent component returns array and this same function is working when used in parent method but when accessed from child component it is not working.

> Working Link :
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gcgxgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fslide1%2Fslide1.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The [EventEmitter.emit()](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) method returns void, so its return value has no 'length' property.**

I suggest that you read the docs about [Components interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Cheers

Comment: Can you please suggest some other solution because i'm new to angular and don't have much idea

Comment: your line should be `this.answer.emit({ Res: '', Ans: '' });` not `var res = this.answer.emit({ Res: '', Ans: '' });`

Comment: @user3653474 sure, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to call parent method from child by passing some values to those two parameter i.e. `Res and Ans` and these values will be processed by `parent component` method and then it will return array which will be used by `child component` should i use that function as a service?

Comment: Using a service to pass data is definitely good, but depending on your structure/project you might want to call this 'fetch' function from the parent component and pass the response to the children using input binding

Comment: Thanks will creating seperate `.ts` file also works because data will not be shared between components.